# Faster search than find

Tags: linux, debian, find, search, locate

Is there a way to find things faster than `find` . I am/was doing :-

```
$sudo find / -perm +4000
```

But it takes ages to find the required info. and I know that most of the files which would that specific permission bit set would be static/not dynamic.

I tried

```
[$] sudo locate --all / -perm +4000                                                                                               
locate: invalid option -- 'p'
```

but as can be seen failed. Any ideas how could I use locate to do the same thing.

Just to share `/usr/bin/locate` is sym-linked to `/etc/alternatives/locate` which in-turn is sym-linked to `/usr/bin/mlocate`

Comment: You need to wait for some time to produce the desired output. If you only have to find files with specific pattern then `locate` is good.

Comment: If you only want to search the root filesystem rather than every possible filesystem mounted (nfs, /proc etc etc) add -xdev.  e.g. `find / -xdev -perm +4000`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `mlocate` does not index file permissions, so you'll have to resort to scanning your filesystems with `find`, unless you find a locate implementation that features this functionality (or extend `mlocate` yourself).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @shirish, mlocate does not index file permissions.
But stil I have some suggestions for you:

Firstly, from find manual, -perm +mode is deprecated, so you should use -perm /mode instead.

> **-perm +mode**
>
> Deprecated, old way of searching for files with any of the permission bits in mode set.  You should use -perm /mode instead.
> Trying to use the '+' syntax with symbolic modes will  yield  surprising  results.   For  example,  '+u+x'  is a valid symbolic mode (equivalent to +u,+x, i.e. 0111) and will therefore not be evaluated as -perm +mode but instead as the exact mode specifier -perm mode and so it matches files with exact permissions 0111 instead of files with any execute bit set.  If you found this paragraph confusing, you're not alone  -  just  use  -perm
> /mode. This  form  of  the  -perm  test  is  deprecated because the POSIX specification requires the interpretation of a leading '+' as being part of a symbolic mode, and so we switched to using '/' instead.
>
> **-perm /mode**
>
> Any  of  the  permission bits mode are set for the file.  Symbolic modes are accepted in this form.  You must specify 'u', 'g'
> or 'o' if you use a symbolic mode.  See the EXAMPLES section for
> some illustrative examples.  If no permission bits in mode are set, this test matches any file (the idea here is to be
> consistent with the behaviour of -perm -000).

Secondly, you can try to speed up find: to do so, you need to be as specific, as it possible. For example:

```
find /some/path ...
```

will reduce search time, because you specified path where to search (/some/path), instead of searching whole root directory (/)

And lastly, you can exclude system folders, which you don't want to scan during search. For example:

```
 find /some/path -not \( -path /excluded/path -prune \) -name *.js
```

Comment: from which manual did you get the above ?  I tried both the manuals of locate and mlocate but didn't find it there. Am using mlocate as seen from `[$] sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep locate                                                                         [3:08:05]
locate                         manual   /usr/bin/mlocate`

Comment: OR `[$] sudo update-alternatives --config locate                                                                                      
There are 2 choices for the alternative locate (providing /usr/bin/locate).

  Selection    Path                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/mlocate            80        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/locate.findutils   20        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/mlocate            80        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: `

Comment: @shirish as I sad, it is "from find manual", like `man find`, it is not about any `locate`

Comment: I tried again but came up cropper, using the same generic method from before. `[$] sudo find / -not \(-prune \) -perm/mode 4000                                                                                    
[sudo] password for shirish: 
find: paths must precede expression: (-prune
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression] ` confused :(

Comment: @shirish well, first: you should specify excluded path, rather than just write _prune_: `find / -not \( -path /path/to/excluded/folder -prune \)`. Secondly, you are using wrong synax for _-perm_, so your full command should look like this: `find / -not \( -path /path/to/excluded/folder -prune \) -perm /4000`